# How do I dynamically specify the language in the intl.numberformat() function based on the currency?

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

As you can see below, when using the wrong language code, the formatting is not correct in terms of how it should look for users from those countries. So how can I dynamically set this country code based on the currency that is being used? In my app I already know the currency based on mapping a country code I got from geo location to the currency code. Is it possible to map the currency code to the language code some how?

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-us', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(49.99));
// Gives €49.99, Desired: 49,99 €

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-us', { style: 'currency', currency: 'NOK' }).format(49.99));
// Gives NOK 49.99, Desired: kr. 49.99 

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-us', { style: 'currency', currency: 'DKK' }).format(49.99));
// Gives DKK 49.99, Desired: 49.99 kr.
```

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/48632745/5289334

Comment: @c0m1t That post does not explain HOW I set the locale to be equal to the users locale which is what I am trying to do

Comment: It says: `So I think that you should use the same locale (the current user locale) for all the formatting.` You format a number with an arbitrary locale. Then you can add the currency using an object mapping the locale to the currency. Or you can use [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: Why are you passing `en-US` everywhere if that's not the format you want?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to map the currency code to the language code some how?

No, this is impossible. A currency might be used in any number of countries, where any number of languages might be spoken. There is no universal currency-to-language mapping. (You could come up with one yourself, but it likely would be wrong).

> In my app I already know the currency based on mapping a country code I got from geo location to the currency code.

You'll want to derive the language code from that country code or geolocation instead, and pass that as the locale argument to the `Intl.NumberFormat` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The language is defined by the `1ocale`. For danmark that's `da-DK`, so

```js
console.log(
  new Intl.NumberFormat('da-DK', { style: 'currency', currency: 'DKK' })
    .format(49.99) );
    
console.log(
  new Intl.NumberFormat('no', { style: 'currency', currency: 'NOK' })
    .format(49.99) );

console.log(
  new Intl.NumberFormat('en', 
    { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR', currencyDisplay: "name"} )
    .format(49.99) );
```

Comment: I understand, but how can I set the locale dynamically for ANY selected currency?

Comment: Maybe this [little stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-jujvyy?file=script.js) helps you along

Answer (score -1):

You can use `toLocalString` prototype on numbers:

```
function formatCurrency(number, locales, options = {}) {
  return number.toLocaleString(locales, {
    style: "currency", // Default options
    ...options,
  });
}
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)