# JavaScript How to get ISO 4217 currency code from locale

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I need to obtain a currency code for use in Intl.NumberFormat, given a locale string in JavaScript.

Examples of locale strings and corresponding ISO 4217 currency codes:

```
'en-US' --> 'USD'
'en-GB' --> 'GBP'
```

For example: How would I obtain 'GBP' just from the locale string 'en-GB' using JavaScript?

More detailed description of the question:

Intl.NumberFormat() requires a currency property, as shown in the code example below. How can I get that code, just from the locale string using JavaScript?

The specifications state: "*There is no default value; if the style is "currency", the currency property must be provided.*"

If you do not supply a currency, you get error: "*TypeError: Currency code is required with currency style at new NumberFormat()*".

```
const amount = -3500;
new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "USD", // How to get this ISO 4217 currency code?
}).format(amount);
```

JavaScipt has a list of these currency codes, as evidenced by the results of this function call, but I do not know how to convert a locale to one of these codes. How is that done in JavaScript?

```
var currencies = Intl.supportedValuesOf("currency");
```

Comment: Shouldn't the currency be the same no matter the language? Because a 100 USD doesn't equal a 100 GBP

Comment: If an item’s cost changes depending on the country, I’d say there’s some shady business going on.

Answer (score 1):

> *For example: How would I obtain 'GBP' just from the locale string 'en-GB' using JavaScript?*

Just because your locale is `en-GB` (speaks/prefers British English) does not assume that you are dealing in `GBP` (English pounds). You could live in another part of the world and deal in other currencies that are not tied to Britain.

As [Bergi explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73269615/1762224):

> *"No, this is impossible. A currency might be used in any number of countries, where any number of languages might be spoken. There is no universal currency-to-language mapping. (You could come up with one yourself, but it likely would be wrong)."*

You would have to created your own look-up and formatter function. I assume you want to retrieve the currency for a given country.

**Note:** Instead of relying on a locale, maybe you should create a mapping of ISO 316 country codes (alpha-2 or alpha-3) to their preferred ISO 4217 currency code?

Anyways, here is a naïve locale to currency code conversion lookup:

```js
const localeToCurrency = {
  'de-DE': 'EUR', // Germany
  'en-GB': 'GBP', // UK
  'en-US': 'USD', // US
};
const formatCurrencyForLocale = (amount, locale = 'en-US') =>
  amount.toLocaleString(locale, {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: localeToCurrency[locale] ?? 'USD'
  });

const amount = 4.20;
console.log(formatCurrencyForLocale(amount));          // USD, default
console.log(formatCurrencyForLocale(amount, 'de-DE')); // EUR, Euro
console.log(formatCurrencyForLocale(amount, 'en-GB')); // GBP, GB Pound
console.log(formatCurrencyForLocale(amount, 'en-US')); // USD, US Dollar
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Output

```
$4.20
4,20 €
£4.20
$4.20
```

---

## Edit

You would have to create some kind of database that links countries to currency by preferred language or something...

```js
const countries = [
  { id: 1, alpha: 'US' },
  { id: 2, alpha: 'GB' },
  { id: 3, alpha: 'DE' }
];

const currencies = [
  { id: 1, alpha: 'USD' },
  { id: 2, alpha: 'GBP' },
  { id: 3, alpha: 'EUR' }
];

const countryLanguages = [
  { id: 1, countryId: 1, locale: 'en-US' },
  { id: 2, countryId: 2, locale: 'en-GB' },
  { id: 3, countryId: 3, locale: 'de-DE' }
];

const countryCurrency = [
  { id: 1, countryId: 1, currencyId: 1 },
  { id: 2, countryId: 2, currencyId: 2 },
  { id: 3, countryId: 3, currencyId: 3 }
];

const localeToCurrency = countryLanguages.reduce((acc, mapping) => {
  const { countryId, locale } = mapping;
  const { id: curId } = countryCurrency.find(({ countryId: c }) => c === countryId) ?? {};
  const { alpha } = currencies.find(({ id }) => id === curId) ?? {};
  return { ...acc, [locale]: alpha };
}, {});

// Generated lookup
console.log(localeToCurrency);

const formatCurrencyForLocale = (amount, locale = 'en-US') =>
  amount.toLocaleString(locale, {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: localeToCurrency[locale] ?? 'USD'
  });

const amount = 4.20;
console.log(formatCurrencyForLocale(amount));          // USD, default
console.log(formatCurrencyForLocale(amount, 'de-DE')); // EUR, Euro
console.log(formatCurrencyForLocale(amount, 'en-GB')); // GBP, GB Pound
console.log(formatCurrencyForLocale(amount, 'en-US')); // USD, US Dollar
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

For more information on ISO country, language, and currency codes see:

- https://www.iban.com/country-codes
- https://www.iban.com/currency-codes
- https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php
- https://www.fincher.org/Utilities/CountryLanguageList.shtml
- https://help.tradestation.com/10_00/eng/tsdevhelp/elobject/class_el/lcid_values.htm